# how to use ' > ' or ' < ' in if condition jquery with margin left?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, margin-left

ex :

```
 if ( $div.css('marginLeft') == '-2000px') {

 } ..... it is working but i want to check it like

 if ( $div.css('marginLeft') > '-2000px') {

 } ...... Not working
```

Comment: You could `parseInt()` it first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `'-2000px'` is a string, and not a number. You cannot use `>` and `<` on strings in this way.

Try *parsing* `$div.css` as an *integer*, and writing the pixels as an integer (without the `''`):

```
if ( parseInt( $div.css('marginLeft') ) > -2000 ){
```

Comment: I'm glad! Please remember to mark this answer as 'correct'.

Comment: i have one more question please , how can i write a code in else to do nothing or stop the code in if or else if ?

Comment: You do not need to include an `else` or an `else if`. All you need is `if(...){ ... }`